# O365 Python not able to access emails in mailbox - access denied error

Tags: python, python-3.x

After the recent changes made by Microsoft to disable basic authentication, IMAP lib is not working to retrieve emails from an O365 mailbox.

We are trying to use below code to retrieve the mails but it is giving below error:

```
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@company.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?%24top=25 | Error Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

Below is the python code used. We have created an application in Azure and app is being granted to Mail.read, Mail.readwrite, User.read, Application.readall permissions.

```
user_id = "user_id"
cient_id = 'client_id'
client_secret = 'client_secret'
tenant_id = 'tenant_id'

from O365 import Account

credentials = (cient_id, client_secret)
scopes = ['offline_access']

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id=tenant_id)
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
 
mailbox = account.mailbox(resource=user_id)
inbox = mailbox.inbox_folder()

for message in inbox.get_messages():
    print(message)
```

Any guidance/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Usually for those permissions admin consent is required. Are you sure that the admin consent is also granted for them?

Comment: Yes the admin consent is granted. I confirmed with Azure Admin.

Comment: I've executed the exact same snippet that you provided here, with my own credentials and I can verify that it is working at my end. There is also an application access policy feature that might restricting your application from accessing the resource you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access
You might verify with your admin if that is causing some problems?